# Java Swing GUI Client and Server Chat App TextArea not updating

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, textarea

I am doing a Chat Application using Java and Swing class for GUI.

The ChatServer class will be the server receiving message from clients and echo back to all clients but I only intend to make the chat for 2 clients.

The ChatClient class is both of the client. They display what was sent from the server on the Text Area. And send texts in the Text Field to the server.

**ChatClient Class**

```
package chatclient;

import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ChatClient extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public ChatClient() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    scrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    textArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    btnConnect = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnDisconnect = new javax.swing.JButton();
    lblStatus = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblShowStatus = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtInput = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Chat Client A");

    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setColumns(20);
    textArea.setRows(5);
    textArea.setText("Welcome to the Chat Server. Type '/close' or Click 'Disconnect' to close.");
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);

    btnConnect.setText("Connect");
    btnConnect.setActionCommand("btnConnect");
    btnConnect.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            btnConnectMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    btnDisconnect.setText("Disconnect");
    btnDisconnect.setActionCommand("btnDisconnect");
    btnDisconnect.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnDisconnectActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    lblStatus.setText("Status: ");

    lblShowStatus.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    lblShowStatus.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
    lblShowStatus.setText("Disconnected");

    txtInput.setToolTipText("");
    txtInput.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            txtInputActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(scrollPane)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(btnConnect)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(btnDisconnect)
                    .addGap(42, 42, 42)
                    .addComponent(lblStatus)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(lblShowStatus)
                    .addGap(0, 42, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addComponent(txtInput))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(scrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 213, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 11, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(txtInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(btnConnect)
                .addComponent(btnDisconnect)
                .addComponent(lblStatus)
                .addComponent(lblShowStatus))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnConnectMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    lblShowStatus.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    lblShowStatus.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 51));
    lblShowStatus.setText("Connected");

    // ADD CODES FOR CONNECTING TO CHAT SERVER

}                                       

private void btnDisconnectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    lblShowStatus.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    lblShowStatus.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
    lblShowStatus.setText("Disconnected");

    // ADD CODES FOR DISCONNECTING FROM CHAT SERVER

}                                             

private void txtInputActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>      

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ChatClient().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    String input = "", serverInput = "";
    String host = "localhost";
    int port = 1337;
    Socket client;

    // updateTextArea("TEST UPDATE");

    try {
        client = new Socket(host, port);
        System.out.println("Connected to Server!");

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

        System.out.println("Before setting text area");
        updateTextArea("trying to update");

        do {
            // HANDLE INPUT PART HERE
            serverInput = in.readUTF();


            if(serverInput != null) {
                System.out.println("Reached here");
                System.out.println(serverInput);
                updateTextArea(serverInput); 
            }

        } while(!input.equals("/close"));
        System.out.println("Program closed");
    }    

    catch(Exception exc) {
        System.err.println(exc.getMessage());
    }


}

private static void updateTextArea(String temp) {
    textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\n" + temp + "\n");
    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnConnect;
private javax.swing.JButton btnDisconnect;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblShowStatus;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblStatus;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane scrollPane;
private static javax.swing.JTextArea textArea;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtInput;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**ChatServer Class**

```
package chatserver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
// for testing
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 *
 * @author wacats
 */
public class ChatServer {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int port = 1337;

    try {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
        String inMessage = "";

        while(true) {
            Socket clientA = server.accept();
            DataInputStream inA = new DataInputStream(clientA.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream outA = new DataOutputStream(clientA.getOutputStream());
            // outA.writeUTF("Welcome to the Chat Server. Type '/close' or Click 'Disconnect' to close.");

            // for testing
            // BufferedReader user = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            do {
                inMessage = inA.readUTF();

                outA.writeUTF("testing");

                if(inMessage != null) {
                   outA.writeUTF(inMessage); 
                }

            } while(!inMessage.equals("/close"));
            clientA.close();
        }



    }

    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

My idea on the process of this program is:

1. Launch ChatServer
2. Launch ChatClient
3. When both clients are connected to the server, they can start chatting.
4. Pressing "Enter" will send the texts in Text Field to the server.
5. Server will broadcast the text to both client.
6. Client will update the Text Area appending the text received from server.

Comment: You need to update your text area in Swing thread. You probably need to make the call of method `updateTextArea` wrapped by the method `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

Comment: And void `static` references; use `append` over `setText`

Comment: You have `NullPointerException` in your `updateTextArea` because the loop to read/write content from the server is been allowed to run before the UI is established

Comment: Change `System.err.println(exc.getMessage());` to `exc.printStackTrace();` and you'll see why

Comment: @MadProgrammer how do i access to the text area without using static?

Comment: You pass it as a reference to what ever class should be handling reading the input OR you have a reader class which generate input events through which you can update the text area from within the class it's defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is, `textArea` is `null` when you try and call `updateTextArea`, this is because the `invokeLater` call hasn't executed yet and constructed your UI, you basically have a race condition.

The normal way to deal with `Socket`s in Swing is, is to use a `SwingWorker`

Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details.

There are a number of ways you could solve you problem.  You could use the `SwingWorker` to read the text from the socket and generate update notifications (through the `publish`/`process`) methods, this is commonly known as an "observer pattern".  This is good as it de-couples your code and generates a more reusable solution.

## `SocketReader`

All this class does is reads text from the `Socket` and generates `ActionEvent`s from the text, simple.

```
public class SocketReader extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    private List<ActionListener> actionListeners;

    public SocketReader() {
        actionListeners = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        actionListeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        actionListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Connected to Server!");

        try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(SocketManager.INSTACNE.getInputStream())) {

            System.out.println("Before setting text area");

            String serverInput = null;
            do {
                // HANDLE INPUT PART HERE
                serverInput = in.readUTF();

                if (serverInput != null) {
                    System.out.println("Read " + serverInput);
                    publish(serverInput);
                }

            } while (!serverInput.equals("/close"));
            System.out.println("Program closed");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        for (String text : chunks) {
            ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, text);
            for (ActionListener listener : actionListeners) {
                listener.actionPerformed(evt);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

## `SocketWriter`

This simple writes text to the `Socket`, simple.  Technically, you don't need to use a `SwingWorker` for this, but I like the fact that it's relatively easy to cancel

```
public class SocketWriter extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    private List<String> messages;
    private ReentrantLock lock;
    private Condition waitCon;

    public SocketWriter() {
        messages = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>(25));
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
        waitCon = lock.newCondition();
    }

    public void write(String text) {
        System.out.println("Write " + text);
        messages.add(text);
        try {
            lock.lock();
            waitCon.signalAll();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        try (DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(SocketManager.INSTACNE.getOutputStream())) {
            while (!isCancelled()) {
                while (messages.isEmpty() && !isCancelled()) {
                    try {
                        lock.lock();
                        waitCon.await();
                    } finally {
                        lock.unlock();
                    }
                }
                List<String> cache = new ArrayList<>(messages);
                messages.clear();
                for (String text : cache) {
                    System.out.println("Send " + text);
                    out.writeUTF(text);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

## `SocketManager`

Okay, this is slightly overkill on my part, but I want a central controller for the `Socket`, you don't have to use a singleton, you could simply make it a simple class and pass a reference of it to your `ChatClient` and on down to the `SocketReader/Writer`, but it's late and I'm lazy

```
public enum SocketManager {
    INSTACNE;

    private String host = "localhost";
    private int port = 1337;
    private Socket socket;

    public Socket open() throws IOException {
        if (socket != null) {
            close();
        }
        socket = new Socket(host, port);
        return socket;
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (socket == null) {
            return;
        }
        socket.close();
    }

    public boolean isOpen() {
        return socket != null
            && socket.isConnected()
            && !socket.isClosed()
            && !socket.isInputShutdown()
            && !socket.isOutputShutdown();
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(socket, "Socket is not open");
        return socket.getInputStream();
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(socket, "Socket is not open");
        return socket.getOutputStream();
    }
}
```

## `ChatClient`

That's all nice a awesome and all, but how are you suppose to use it?

Will, very basically, you create an instance of `SocketReader` and `SocketWriter` in your `ChatClient`, you attach an `ActionListener` to the reader and update the `JTextArea` when it's triggered and send the text you want sent to the `SocketWriter`, for example...

```
public class ChatClient extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public ChatClient() {
        initComponents();
        socketReader = new SocketReader();
        socketReader.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String text = e.getActionCommand();
                textArea.append(text);
                textArea.append("\n");
                textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
            }
        });
        socketReader.execute();

        socketWriter = new SocketWriter();
        socketWriter.execute();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        scrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        textArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        btnConnect = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnDisconnect = new javax.swing.JButton();
        lblStatus = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblShowStatus = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtInput = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Chat Client A");

        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setColumns(20);
        textArea.setRows(5);
        textArea.setText("Welcome to the Chat Server. Type '/close' or Click 'Disconnect' to close.");
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);

        btnConnect.setText("Connect");
        btnConnect.setActionCommand("btnConnect");
        btnConnect.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                btnConnectMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        btnDisconnect.setText("Disconnect");
        btnDisconnect.setActionCommand("btnDisconnect");
        btnDisconnect.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnDisconnectActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        lblStatus.setText("Status: ");

        lblShowStatus.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        lblShowStatus.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
        lblShowStatus.setText("Disconnected");

        txtInput.setToolTipText("");
        txtInput.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtInputActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(scrollPane)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(btnConnect)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(btnDisconnect)
                        .addGap(42, 42, 42)
                        .addComponent(lblStatus)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(lblShowStatus)
                        .addGap(0, 42, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(txtInput))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(scrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 213, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 11, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(txtInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnConnect)
                    .addComponent(btnDisconnect)
                    .addComponent(lblStatus)
                    .addComponent(lblShowStatus))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnConnectMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        lblShowStatus.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        lblShowStatus.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 51));
        lblShowStatus.setText("Connected");

        // ADD CODES FOR CONNECTING TO CHAT SERVER
    }

    private void btnDisconnectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        lblShowStatus.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        lblShowStatus.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
        lblShowStatus.setText("Disconnected");

        // ADD CODES FOR DISCONNECTING FROM CHAT SERVER
    }

    private void txtInputActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if (SocketManager.INSTACNE.isOpen()) {
            socketWriter.write(txtInput.getText());
        } else {
            System.out.println("!! Not open");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
            /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
            * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
             */
            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //</editor-fold>

            SocketManager.INSTACNE.open();

            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new ChatClient().setVisible(true);
                }
            });

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        //</editor-fold>      

    }

    private SocketWriter socketWriter;
    private SocketReader socketReader;

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnConnect;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnDisconnect;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblShowStatus;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblStatus;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea textArea;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtInput;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

You'll note, I used `SocketManager#open` in the `main`, sorry, missed you "connect" code.  I would suggest moving that to that method instead ;)

## `ChatServer`

I didn't make to much of change to this, but just in case...

```
public class ChatServer {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int port = 1337;

        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
            String inMessage = "";

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Waiting");
                Socket clientA = server.accept();
                System.out.println("Connected");
                DataInputStream inA = new DataInputStream(clientA.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream outA = new DataOutputStream(clientA.getOutputStream());
                // outA.writeUTF("Welcome to the Chat Server. Type '/close' or Click 'Disconnect' to close.");

                // for testing
                // BufferedReader user = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                do {
                    inMessage = inA.readUTF();

                    if (inMessage != null) {
                        outA.writeUTF(inMessage);
                    }

                } while (!inMessage.equals("/close"));
                clientA.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Normally, when a client connects, you'd start a new `Thread` and have it process the client `Socket`, but that wasn't my focus.

So, based on all that, you have a lot of reading to catch up on, including [Concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) and [All About Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

Comment: NetBeans is complaining about the `static` keyword at the class declaration

Comment: @wacats Then take them out, I had the code setup in a single file for simplicity while testing, forgot to remove them :P

Comment: when I launch 2 different ChatClient class, they only show their own sent message instead of sync-ing the messages between each other, I thought it was because of my wrong implementation of multithreading at ChatClient. Follow up question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163293/making-a-new-thread-in-java-swing-gui-chat-app

Comment: *"Normally, when a client connects, you'd start a new Thread and have it process the client Socket, but that wasn't my focus."* - There are examples in [All About Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) trail