# Making a new Thread in Java Swing GUI Chat App

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets, user-interface

Previous Question: [Java Swing GUI Client and Server Chat App TextArea not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155909/java-swing-gui-client-and-server-chat-app-textarea-not-updating)

I am making a Chat App on Java using Swing Class. I have done the multithreading part on the server part of it.

Note that the server is supposed to serve two clients chatting to each other instead of one of them as host and one of them as client.

**ChatServer**

```
public class ChatServer {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    final int port = 1337;

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket socket = null;

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    while(true) {
        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        new Thread(new Handler(socket)).start();
    }


}
}
```

**Handler (for ChatServer)**

```
public class Handler implements Runnable {
private Socket socket;

public Handler(Socket s) {
    socket = s;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        String inMessage = "";

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Waiting");
            System.out.println("Connected");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            do {
                inMessage = in.readUTF();

                if(inMessage != null) {
                    out.writeUTF(inMessage);
                }
            } while(!inMessage.equals("/close"));
            socket.close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Now on a different package as ChatClient, I would like to make my ChatClient support multi-threading as well.

**ChatClient**

```
public class ChatClient extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public ChatClient() {
    initComponents();
    socketReader = new SocketReader();
    socketReader.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = e.getActionCommand();
            textArea.append("\n");
            textArea.append(text);
            textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
            txtInput.setText("");
    }
});
    socketReader.execute();

    socketWriter = new SocketWriter();
    socketWriter.execute();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    scrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    textArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    btnConnect = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnDisconnect = new javax.swing.JButton();
    lblStatus = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblShowStatus = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtInput = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Chat Client");

    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setColumns(20);
    textArea.setRows(5);
    textArea.setText("Welcome to the Chat Server. Type '/close' or Click 'Disconnect' to close.");
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);

    btnConnect.setText("Connect");
    btnConnect.setActionCommand("btnConnect");
    btnConnect.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            btnConnectMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    btnDisconnect.setText("Disconnect");
    btnDisconnect.setActionCommand("btnDisconnect");
    btnDisconnect.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnDisconnectActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    lblStatus.setText("Status: ");

    lblShowStatus.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    lblShowStatus.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
    lblShowStatus.setText("Disconnected");

    txtInput.setToolTipText("");
    txtInput.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            txtInputActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(scrollPane)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(btnConnect)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(btnDisconnect)
                    .addGap(42, 42, 42)
                    .addComponent(lblStatus)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(lblShowStatus)
                    .addGap(0, 211, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addComponent(txtInput))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(25, 25, 25)
            .addComponent(scrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 213, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 28, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(txtInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(btnConnect)
                .addComponent(btnDisconnect)
                .addComponent(lblStatus)
                .addComponent(lblShowStatus))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnConnectMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    lblShowStatus.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    lblShowStatus.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 51));
    lblShowStatus.setText("Connected");

    // ADD CODES FOR CONNECTING TO CHAT SERVER

}                                       

private void btnDisconnectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    lblShowStatus.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    lblShowStatus.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
    lblShowStatus.setText("Disconnected");

    // ADD CODES FOR DISCONNECTING FROM CHAT SERVER

}                                             

private void txtInputActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(SocketManager.INSTACNE.isOpen()) {
        socketWriter.write(txtInput.getText());
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("!! Not open");
    }
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    SocketManager.INSTACNE.open();

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ChatClient().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
    //</editor-fold>       
}

private SocketWriter socketWriter;
private SocketReader socketReader;

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnConnect;
private javax.swing.JButton btnDisconnect;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblShowStatus;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblStatus;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane scrollPane;
private static javax.swing.JTextArea textArea;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtInput;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**SocketReader**

```
public class SocketReader extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

private List<ActionListener> actionListeners;

public SocketReader() {
    actionListeners = new ArrayList<>(25);
}

public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
    actionListeners.add(listener);
}

public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
    actionListeners.remove(listener);
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Connected to Server!");

    try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(SocketManager.INSTACNE.getInputStream())) {

        System.out.println("Before setting text area");

        String serverInput = null;
        do {
            // HANDLE INPUT PART HERE
            serverInput = in.readUTF();

            if (serverInput != null) {
                System.out.println("Read " + serverInput);
                publish(serverInput);
            }

        } while (!serverInput.equals("/close"));
        System.out.println("Program closed");
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
    for (String text : chunks) {
        ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, text);
        for (ActionListener listener : actionListeners) {
            listener.actionPerformed(evt);
        }
    }
}

}
```

**SocketWriter**

```
public class SocketWriter extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

private List<String> messages;
private ReentrantLock lock;
private Condition waitCon;

public SocketWriter() {
    messages = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>(25));
    lock = new ReentrantLock();
    waitCon = lock.newCondition();
}

public void write(String text) {
    System.out.println("Write " + text);
    messages.add(text);
    try {
        lock.lock();
        waitCon.signalAll();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    try (DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(SocketManager.INSTACNE.getOutputStream())) {
        while (!isCancelled()) {
            while (messages.isEmpty() && !isCancelled()) {
                try {
                    lock.lock();
                    waitCon.await();
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
            List<String> cache = new ArrayList<>(messages);
            messages.clear();
            for (String text : cache) {
                System.out.println("Send " + text);
                out.writeUTF(text);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

**SocketManager**

```
public enum SocketManager {
INSTACNE;

private String host = "localhost";
private int port = 1337;
private Socket socket;

public Socket open() throws IOException {
    if (socket != null) {
        close();
    }
    socket = new Socket(host, port);
    return socket;
}

public void close() throws IOException {
    if (socket == null) {
        return;
    }
    socket.close();
}

public boolean isOpen() {
    return socket != null
        && socket.isConnected()
        && !socket.isClosed()
        && !socket.isInputShutdown()
        && !socket.isOutputShutdown();
}

public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    Objects.requireNonNull(socket, "Socket is not open");
    return socket.getInputStream();
}

public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
    Objects.requireNonNull(socket, "Socket is not open");
    return socket.getOutputStream();
}
}
```

I am not sure whether I should do the same way for the Swing GUI in ChatClient as how I did it with ChatServer.

So I would like to know the correct way of doing multithreading on a GUI window especially it now involves other class also.

Comment: What do you need help with exactly? This looks fine. The way you have the threads get created for `ChatClient` is fine. I would put all my fields at the top of my class (you have your's at the bottom in `ChatClient`). This would make it easier to read and glance over. It is also the way it is meant to be.

Comment: @Forseth11 the variables are declared that way because I'm using NetBean's Drag and Drop GUI Builder so it declares the variables at that position. Actually my problem now is I am able to make 2 chat window but the chat content does not sync to each other.

Comment: As I stated in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155909/java-swing-gui-client-and-server-chat-app-textarea-not-updating/44158305?noredirect=1#comment75355781_44158305), one of the problems with your code is the fact that the server is only handling a single connection.  Each client connection will require a `Thread` of it's own to manage them (possibly with a read and write thread), which would "read" messages from clients, probably post them to some kind of `queue`, which the "write" thread would then send to the client

Answer (score 0):

I have created too basic chat application for TCP connection. My code is in three files. One for server, one for client and one for UI. You can implement UI part yourself. I have implemented only basic.

```
Server part:
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ChatServer
{   ServerSocket server;
Socket client;
InputStream is;
OutputStream os;
BufferedReader br;
byte buf[];
String msg;
ChatServer(InetSocketAddress ip)
{   try
    {   server=new ServerSocket();
        server.bind(ip);
        br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        buf=new byte[80];
        System.out.println("Server Listening on IP : "+server.getInetAddress().toString()+" PORT : "+server.getLocalPort());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   e.printStackTrace(); }
}
public void doChat()
{   try
    {   System.out.println("Server Ready");
        int r=0;
        client=server.accept();
        System.out.println("\n\nConnected to client \n IP :"+client.getInetAddress().toString()+" PORT : "+client.getPort());
        is=client.getInputStream();
        os=client.getOutputStream();
        SenderUI sui=new SenderUI("Server",client,os,is);
        while(true)
        {   if((r=is.read(buf,0,80))!=-1)
            {   msg=new String(buf,0,buf.length);
                System.out.println("Client : "+msg);
                for(int i=0;i<80;i++)
                {   buf[i]=0;   }
            }
            else
            {   System.out.println("Error in receiving  ");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)              //IOE,SocketE,UnkownHost etc
    {   e.printStackTrace();    }
    finally
    {   try{    is.close(); os.close(); client.close(); server.close(); }
        catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{   InetSocketAddress ip=null;
    try
    {   ip=new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(args[0]),12345);}
    catch(Exception e)
    {   e.printStackTrace(); return;}
    ChatServer chat=new ChatServer(ip);
    chat.doChat();
}
}
```

Server will create thread as per client requirements.

```
Client Part:
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ChatClient
{   
Socket client;
InputStream is;
OutputStream os;
BufferedReader br;
String msg;
byte buf[];
ChatClient(InetAddress ip,int port)
{   try
    {   client=new Socket(ip,port);
        System.out.println("Connected to server : "+ip.toString());
        is=client.getInputStream();
        os=client.getOutputStream();
        br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        buf=new byte[80];
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   e.printStackTrace(); }
}
public void doChat()
{   try
    {   System.out.println("\n\nCommunication Line acquired \n Start conversation \n");
        SenderUI sui=new SenderUI("Client",client,os,is);
        int r=0;
        while(true)
        {   if((r=is.read(buf,0,80))!=-1)
            {   msg=new String(buf,0,buf.length);
                System.out.println("Server : "+msg);
            }
            else 
            {   System.out.println("Error in receiving"); break; }
            for(int i=0;i<80;i++)
            {   buf[i]=0;   }
        }
    }
    catch(SocketException se)
    {   System.out.println("\nServer Disconnected");}
    catch(Exception e)              //IOE,SocketE,UnkownHost etc
    {   e.printStackTrace();    }
    finally
    {   try{    is.close(); os.close(); client.close(); }
        catch(Exception e){     }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{   InetAddress ip=null;
    int port=0;
    try
    {   ip=InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);
        port=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException ne)
    {   System.out.println("Invalid port number");  return; }
    catch(UnknownHostException e)
    {   System.out.println("Invalid Server IP/Name");   return; }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   e.printStackTrace();    }
    ChatClient chat=new ChatClient(ip,port);
    chat.doChat();
}
}
```

Client will make request to server on specific port.

```
Demo UI:
import java.io.*;
InputStream is;
Socket osck;
JTextArea msgbox;
JButton sendb;
String uname;
SenderUI(String user,Socket osc,OutputStream ost,InputStream ist)
{   super(user);
    this.setSize(300,200);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
    uname=user;
    osck=osc;
    os=ost;
    is=ist;
    msgbox=new JTextArea();
    msgbox.setBounds(5,5,200,100);
    sendb=new JButton("Send");
    sendb.setBounds(5,110,80,30);
    sendb.addActionListener(this);
    this.add(msgbox); this.add(sendb);
    this.addWindowListener(this);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{   String msg=msgbox.getText();
    if(!msg.equals(""))
    {   try
        {   os.write(msg.getBytes());
            System.out.println(uname+" : "+msg);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {   e.printStackTrace();
        }
        msgbox.setText("");
    }
}
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e)
{ }
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e)
{ }
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
{   try 
    {   System.out.println("End of conversation"); 
        os.close(); is.close(); osck.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch(Exception ee)
    {   ee.printStackTrace();   }
}
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e)
{ }
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e)
{ }
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e)
{ }
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e)
{ }
}
```

I have tested it. It works perfectly. If you find any query. Please comment below. Have a nice day.