# Why does my GUI Send Button freeze when Action Listener is run?

Tags: java, button, handler, actionlistener

I am making a chat server with a GUI that connects with a Client

The GUI consists of two text boxes, one for receiving text and one for sending text. And the last thing is the send button, which I am having issues with at the moment.

The send button freezes (the GUI still works, its only the button that freezes) when it is pressed and the message is not sent.

Im not sure what to do here and hoping you guys can help me. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Code:

```
class UdpServer
{
PrintWriter out;
ButtonHandler txButtonHandler;
BufferedReader in;
    DatagramSocket socket;
    InetAddress ip = null;
int port;

    UdpServer (String gport) throws IOException
    {
        int i = 0;
        socket = new DatagramSocket (Integer.parseInt (gport));

  txButtonHandler = new ButtonHandler ();
  sendButton.addActionListener (txButtonHandler);
        new Thread ()
        {
            public void run ()
            {
                try
                {
                    rx ();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                }
            }

        }.start ();
        tx ();
        System.exit (1);
    }

    void tx () throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String toServer;

        do
        {
            toServer = in.readLine();
            toServer = toServer + "\n";
            buf = toServer.getBytes ();
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket (buf, toServer.length(), ip, port);
            if (ip != null) socket.send(packet);
        }
        while (toServer != null);
        socket.close ();
        System.exit (1);
    }

private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) //throws IOException
    {
        try{tx ();} catch (IOException e){}
    }
}

    void rx () throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
        String fromServer;
        do
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i ++) buf[i] = 0;
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket (buf, buf.length);
            socket.receive (packet);
            fromServer = new String (packet.getData());
            ip = packet.getAddress ();
            port = packet.getPort ();
            //System.out.println (port + ":" + ip);
            if (fromServer != null) System.out.print (fromServer);
        }
        while (fromServer != null);
        socket.close ();
        System.exit (1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn how to do threading in Swing from a good tutorial; one basic example while searching on Internet gives this link: https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/swing_ui.shtml

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I've never done threading in Swing, how would I go about starting it in regarding my code?

Comment: This is the reason I've asked you to first learn by going through the tutorials, understanding them fully, and then proceeding with your own development once you understand the threading model of Swing.

Comment: Maybe you should start with [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and  [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: [That's one possible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155909/java-swing-gui-client-and-server-chat-app-textarea-not-updating/44158305#44158305)

Answer (score 0):

Swing has a special Thread responsible for changing the GUI. The Event Dispatch Thread. Methods from ActionListeners are executed on this Thread, this means if they take long the UI freezes. So you have to do the work in an own Thread. Unfortunately if you are in your own Thread and you want to change the UI you have to do this in the Event Dispatch Thread. You can do this with  SwingUtilities.invokeLater.

Here is an example:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Example extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example example = new Example();
        example.setSize(200, 200);
        JButton button = new JButton("Do it");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        button.addActionListener(e -> 
                new Thread(() -> {
                    doLongTask();
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> textField.setText("Did it"));
        }).start());
        example.add(button);
        example.add(textField);
        example.pack();
        example.setVisible(true);
        example.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private static void doLongTask() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```